# How to make an if..else statement that will return true if your checkbox is being clicked?

Tags: html, jquery, input, checkbox, bootstrap-5

I recently having a problem with this if else statement

So both have a specific id name which is "premium" and "regular"

I wanted to make an if else statement using jquery that will return able my input's

Here is what my checkbox need to do,

- if my checkbox is being checked I wanted the input to be enabled
- else nothing happen because it is already disabled.

```js
$("#PreCap").prop('disabled', true);
$("#PreA").prop('disabled', true);

$("#RegCap").prop('disabled', true);
$("#RegA").prop('disabled', true);


//var premium = document.querySelector("#premium").checked;
// var regular = document.getElementById("regular");

$('#premium').val();

if ($("#premium").is(":checked")) {
  $("#PreCap").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#PreA").prop('disabled', false);
} else if (regular.checked === true) {
  document.getElementById("RegCap").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("RegA").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="premium">
<label class="form-check-label" type="checkbox" for="premium">Premium Air Conditioner</label>
<input type="number" id="PreCap" class="form-control" placeholder="Seat Capacity">

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="regular">
<label class="form-check-label" type="checkbox" for="regular">Regular Air conditioner</label>
<input type="number" id="RegCap" class="form-control" placeholder="Seat Capacity">
```

Note: I am using **bootstrap 5** and **jquery-3.5.1.min.js**

Comment: I dont see the click/change event of `$("#premium")`. If you don't have that event not much happens

Comment: *is being checked* - is in the process of being ticked?  Then you'll definitely need an event.  There's no "being checked" *other* than in an event - outside the event it is either already ticked or already not ticked, there's no "in process of" ([being])

Comment: You have an answer below, but check the [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) documentation for :checked Selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  $('#premium').click(function(){
 
    $("#PreCap").prop('disabled', !$(this).is(":checked"));
 
        
});

$('#regular').click(function(){
    $("#RegCap").prop('disabled', !$(this).is(":checked"));
        
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).prop("checked") == true)` is cleaner like this: `if($(this).is(":checked"))` or just `if (this.checked)` and why mix jQuery and DOM? If you HAVE to mix, please do `document.getElementById("RegCap").disabled = !this.checked` instead of using if and else - jQuery: `$("#PreCap").prop('disabled',!this.checked)`

Comment: That looks fine now. Thanks for making it much simpler.

Comment: That almost looks like mine now actually

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this

I added a class to bot checkboxes called `air`

On click of either, I set the disabled to NOT what is checked

Also I call the change event on load so the input fields are set to whatever the chekboxes are at load time

Yo can add the RegA and PreA whatever that is if needed

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $(".air").on("change", function() {
    $("#PreCap").prop('disabled', !$("#premium").is(":checked"));
    $("#RegCap").prop('disabled', !$("#regular").is(":checked"));
  }).change(); // when page loads, trigger the event
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input air" id="premium">
<label class="form-check-label" for="premium">Premium Air Conditioner</label>
<input type="number" id="PreCap" class="form-control" placeholder="Seat Capacity">

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input air" id="regular">
<label class="form-check-label" for="regular">Regular Air conditioner</label>
<input type="number" id="RegCap" class="form-control" placeholder="Seat Capacity">
```